# pip install not working -- How to install/upgrade PyPi packages with pip v10 and above, using Python?

Tags: python-3.x, pip, python-3.6, python-3.7

After upgrading my `pip` to version `10` using `pip3 install --upgrade pip` and above I cannot  I want to install/upgrade PyPi packages using `pip3 install PyPiPackageName` as I get the following error:

```
from pip import main
ImportError: cannot import name main
```

I wonder how I can install PyPi packages using `pip` when I'm using new versions of `pip`? I've seen some people use `pyhton3` to do this but doing `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` gave me the following error and I cannot upgrade pip to higher versions:

```
/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip
```

Before doing `python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip` I do `python3 -m pip install -U pip` and I get the following error:

`/usr/bin/python3: No module named pip`

So I'm confused on what I need to do to be able to upgrade or install PyPi packages.

Comment: I think you don't have your pip installed in your machine maybe you first need to install pip using **python3 -m pip install -U pip**. And then try **python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip** to upgrade your pip and install your package.

Comment: @markkeven It's so strange because I followed [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/a/865569/262267) to install Python 3.6 for Ubuntu 16.10LTS  and then do `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.6`. So do you mean I didn't need to do `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.6`?

Comment: I had the same issue in my window machine so I did **python3 -m pip install -U pip** then I was able to install the package correctly. I have not tried in any other platform like Ubuntu. Give a try using the **python3 -m pip install -U pip** and it might amaze you.

Comment: @markkeven It didn't work. Look at my quesiton again ...

Comment: Pip already comes pre-installed with Python 3.6

Comment: @cricket_007 So maybe doing `curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.6` is causing these issues. Right?

Comment: By the way @mark `-U` and `--upgrade` are the same flag on the CLI, so only one would need ran

Comment: Probably, I personally haven't ran that command in Python versions that already had pip. You should've tried using pip before running that script. Though I would assume that script first checks if pip is available so that it wouldn't override it... As far as Ubuntu goes, `pip3` might be available as a command

Comment: Maybe something like this could help https://askubuntu.com/questions/969463/python3-pip3-install-broken-on-ubuntu

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to executing the following:

```
curl https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py | python3.6
```

I also had to make sure `python3` is using Python 3.6 otherwise Python 3.5 is used (which does not come with `pip` by default). So I did the following and things work fine now:

```
ln -s /usr/bin/python3.6 /usr/local/bin/python3
```

Answer (score 0):

The installation must use the Python installation tool, namely the default pip (pypa) on the computer, if you can't install it on high level, please install low level $ curl -sSL https://bootstrap.pypa.io/get-pip.py -o get -pip.py
$ python get-pip.py